# Conceptual Semantics diagrams

Tags: tables, diagrams, linguistics, semantics

for a university assignment I have to typeset this kind of diagrams (from Jackendoff's Conceptual Semantics framework). I'm not that familiar with LaTeX's handling of matrixes, tikz and so on, so I wondered whether any of you has an idea about how I can draw these in a smart way :)
Thank you!

[image]

So far, I've tried with the avm package - something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{avm}

\begin{document} 
\avmfont{\sc}
\avmoptions{sorted,bottom}
\avmsortfont{\sc}



\begin{avm}
    \[ {mat} {\rm -b,+i} \cr
         pl \[ {} \[ {}
                {\rm +b,-i} \cr
                teapot
            \] \]
        \]
\end{avm}
\end{document
```

But I can't manage to put the labels *inside* the brackets, as in the picture. Moreover, there are a whole lot of placement and spacing issues.

Comment: I added in the question the solution I've gone for so far. Hope it helps :)

Comment: `avm` package does not appear to be in my TeXlive 2015.  Does it really redefine `\[` ?

Comment: No, I had to download it and import it via `\input avm.sty`. And yes, it redefines `\[` inside its own environment, apparently

Comment: Where did you get `avm.sty` from? Normally, I'd check CTAN first but it is down.

Comment: Yep, I got it from CTAN (right before it went down apparently, how lucky). The doc is here (http://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/tex/avm-doc.pdf), but it doesn't really help me...

Answer (score 2):

I can't help but feel that there should be a better package somewhere if this is a standard notation. This is most inelegant - not to say hackish.

Note that I've switched to LaTeX font commands. `\bf`, `\rm` etc. should not be used in LaTeX as they were made obsolete by 2e a couple of decades ago. (I think the documentation uses them because it is intended to be usable with other formats - not just LaTeX.)

`cfr-lm` is loaded to get the italic small-caps Latin Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[rm=lining,sf=lining,tt=lining]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{avm}
\begin{document}
\avmfont{\scshape}
\avmoptions{bottom,sorted}
\avmsortfont{\sishape}
\newcommand*\labelme[1]{\rlap{\hskip .5em #1}}
\begin{avm}
  \[{\labelme{mat}} {\upshape -b,+i} \\
     & pl \[{}
            \[{\labelme{mat}}
              {\upshape +b,-i} \\
              teapot \\[1em]
            \]
       \] \\
  \]
\end{avm}
\end{document}
```

[image: AVM, hacked]

Comment: It's not elegant, it's hackish, and it works perfectly! :) Thank you very much.